# Coloring finite subsets of a fixed size with a single modular function

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $k$ and $N$ be positive integers so that $k\mid N$.  Let $M=(k/N){N\choose k}$. A function $f:[N]^k\rightarrow M$ is a coloring function if $f(s_1) = f(s_2)$ implies that $s_1=s_2$ or $s_1 \cap s_2 = \emptyset $.  Coloring functions exist for all $k$ and $N$ by Baranyai's theorem. When $k=2$, $M=N-1$ and it is widely known and easily shown that there is a function $f(i,j)$, such that for every even $N$, $f(s)=f(i,j)\bmod (N-1)$ is a coloring function for 2 and N where $s =\langle i, j \rangle$, $0 \leq i < j < N$. My question is whether there can exist for a $k>2$ an $f(i_0,i_1, \dotsc, i_{k-1})$ so that $f(\langle i_0,i_1, \dotsc, i_{k-1}\rangle) =  f(i_0,i_1, \dotsc, i_{k-1})\bmod M$ is a coloring function for all $N$ that are multiples of $k$. Probably not but I'd have no idea how to prove it.